# Treat require as import in a .ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when require is used in the .js file, for example `const fs = require('fs')` the variable `fs` has proper typings as if it was imported (i.e. `import * as fs from 'fs'`). But when the same code is used in a .ts file and `fs` is given the any type.

Is there a way to make it so the `require` function in a .ts file has typings just like in a .js file where it is treated as import?

Comment: When using `--module commonjs`, `--module amd`, or `--module umd` `import fs = require('fs');` will give you the desired types. Note that nether `const fs = require('fs');` nor `import fs = require('fs');` are equivalent to `import * as fs from 'fs';`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad In this case I can't use the import keyword because then it treats the file as a module and the functions I define aren't available in other typescript files.

Comment: You're trying to mix a bunch of things together that don't work well together and appear to be relying on the presence or absence of transpilation and language specific loader behavior to get your code to work in the first place. Also, you shouldn't use global variables and if you do you should be explicit about it